# Conteúdo Responsivo com lateral sobrando

Tags: css, css3

Galera, estou tentando passar um conteúdo para responsivo, porém estou tendo dificuldades, segui alguns artigos pela internet sobre, e cheguei a este resultado

Porém está não estou conseguindo fazer o conteúdo ficar 100% fica sempre um espaço sobrando do lado direito seja qual tamanho eu colocar na tela.

Já tentei de tudo e não consigo ver aonde estou errando.

Peço ajuda dos amigos para uma analise dos meus possíveis erros.

Comment: Não tem um passo a passo pra responsivar, depende de site pra site, então olhando apenas um artigo, vai ser difícil você conseguir, se não tiver experiência. Recomendo deixar primeiramente seu layout fluido, trabalhando com porcentagens, etc... E usar media queries e o Flexbox.

Comment: Perguntas que contenham somente link externo podem ser consideradas de baixa qualidade, sendo que o link externo pode ficar inativo a qualquer momento. Deixe o código fonte na pergunta para que no futuro, quando alguém tiver o mesmo problema consiga enxergar o problema e saber como resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema não é o "*espaço sobrando do lado direito*", e sim porque o conteúdo está alinhado à esquerda.

Centralize os elementos em `#wrapper` com `text-align: center;` que resolverá o problema:

```
#wrapper{
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

### EDIT

Além de ser importante centralizar (como descrito acima), é usar a função `calc` do CSS para dividir os elementos na tela. Tomei a liberdade também de ajustar alguns estilos que me pareciam estar aplicados errados, como o `margin` e `padding` nas imagens e nas `<li>`. Veja funcionando com as correções **[neste link](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/patrique.php)**.

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing: 0;
}
body{
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(134,128,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* ff3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(134,128,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* safari4+,chrome */
 background:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(134,128,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */
 background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(134,128,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(134,128,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* ie10+ */
 background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(134,128,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* w3c */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#8680FF', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=1 ); /* ie6-9 */
}
#wrapper{
 padding-top: 20px;
   text-align: center;
}
.nav{
}
.nav li{
 background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 display:inline-block;
 border:0;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
 -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
 -ms-transform: scale(1); 
 -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 transition: all 200ms ease-in;
 transform: scale(1);
 margin: 0px 4px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav li:hover{
 opacity:1;
 z-index: 2;
 -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
 -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
 -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 transition: all 200ms ease-in;
 transform: scale(1.1);
 background:rgba(11, 132, 138, 0.6);
}
img.icon{
 display:block;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
 width:100%;
}
.nav li:hover img.icon{
}
.nav li span{
 text-align:center;
 display:block;
 color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 font-size:0.9em;
 transition:padding-top 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition:padding-top 0.4s;
}
.nav li:hover span{
}
.hm{
 background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 ​position: relative;
 width: calc( (100% - -86px) / 8 );
 padding: 6px 6px 10% 6px;
 xpadding-right: 6px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
 /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
 .hm {
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  padding-bottom: 100%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px) {
 /* Tablet view: 2 tiles */
 .hm {
  width: calc( (100% - 20px) / 2 );
  padding-bottom: 50%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {
 /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
 .hm {
  width: calc( (100% - 64px) / 6 );
  padding-bottom: 33.3%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1290px) and (min-width : 1051px) {
 /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
 .hm {
  width: calc( (100% - -64px) / 8 );
  padding-bottom: 25%;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div id="wrapper">
 <ul class="nav">
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/61/1c/60/611c608f777a4891cada23ef36572b6b--batman-vs-superman--batman-vs-superman-trailer.jpg">
   <span>Batman vs Supe...</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="http://br.web.img3.acsta.net/r_1280_720/pictures/17/03/14/20/37/126690.jpg">
   <span>Meu Malvado...</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="http://br.web.img3.acsta.net/r_1920_1080/pictures/17/04/11/14/14/492957.jpg">
   <span>A Cidade Perdida</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="http://i0.wp.com/pipocamoderna.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/os-vingadores-novo-poster-brasil-630x933.jpg">
   <span>Os Vingadores</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="http://moviesmedia.ign.com/movies/image/object/142/14285520/iron_man3-downey-multipleironmen-poster-610x876.jpg">
   <span>Homem de Ferro 3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/archive/a/ab/20171013162740%21Poster_do_filme_HP7-8.jpg">
   <span>Harry Potter 3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="https://danmoviesnstuff.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/o-homem-de-ac3a7o-poster-teaser-2.jpg">
   <span>O Homem de Aço</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="http://cinedestak.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/X-Men-DFP-poster-nacional-1.jpg">
   <span>X-Men</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="https://loftcinema.org/files/2017/10/dcb432858d20800950b69ca8995eaf07.jpg">
   <span>Mulher Maravilha</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="https://im.ziffdavisinternational.com/ign_br/screenshot/default/warcraft-online-1-sht-colouredsky-brazil-0_m571.jpg">
   <span>WarCraft</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="https://im.ziffdavisinternational.com/ign_br/screenshot/default/angrybirds-onlineposter-brazil_8sqr.jpg">
   <span>Angry Birds</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hm">
   <img class="icon" src="http://cinema10.com.br/upload/filmes/filmes_2472_poste3ligadajustica.jpg">
   <span>Liga da Justiça</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: então, em partes não resolve, eu cheguei até a tentar anteriormente desta forma, porém fica zuado o layout, estou pensando e um uma forma que se adapte 100% no layout e não fique com sobra nem do lado esquerda e nem do lado direito, meu problema está ai, obrigado pelo ajuda.

Comment: @PatriqueAlves Ok, vou ver aqui...

Comment: @PatriqueAlves Editei a pergunta. Dá uma olhada neste link http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/patrique.php

Comment: chique mano, só uma dúvida, o uso do bootstrap é realmente necessário? gostei do code, estarei estudando, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @PatriqueAlves Necessário não é não, mas oferece muitas ferramentas boas. Eu particularmente não gosto. Faço sites responsivos usando jQuery. Abs!